# Created thread is slow

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I encoutered a weird behavior of `pthread_create` function. The code follows:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *foo( void* a) {
    printf("Doing something");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main() {
    printf("Main created");
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create( &thread, NULL, foo, NULL );

    while(1); // This causes trouble

    pthread_join( thread, NULL );

    return 0;
}
```

For some reason, with the `while` in place, message from thread is showed after a really long delay. I would expect that after pthread_create call new thread is completely independent from main and thus should not be afected by its code.

Comment: Have you tried flushing `stdout`?

Comment: @BenSteffan Thank you for comment, in this example it was caused by output buffering.

Comment: the calls to `printf()` are writing to the `stdout` stream buffer.  To get past that buffer and display on the terminal, one of three things has to happen.  1) the buffer overflows (unlikely) 2) the program ends 3) the format string or data ends with '\n' (not being done) So nothing will be output until the program ends.    The `while(1);` loop will NEVER exit, so the program never ends.  Also note: the `main()` is sucking all the CPU cycles with that loop, so nothing is left for the created thread to run.  Suggest: end each `printf()` format string with '\n' and remove the `while()` statement

Comment: since the parameter to the function: `foo()` is not being used, strongly suggest the first statement in that function be: `(void)a;`

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with threads.

You'll find that the same behavior occurs with:

```
printf("Doing something");
while(1) ;
```

This is because you didn't include a newline on the end of the string you printed, which causes the line to be buffered. Since no further output is generated, the line may be buffered for a very long time (possibly even forever).

To avoid this, you can either:

- Add newlines to all of your output lines, e.g. `printf("Doing something\n");`
- Call `fflush(stdout)` after `printf()` to force the line to be flushed
- Call `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0)` beforehand to disable all output buffering

Comment: I would change `while(1);` to `while(1){usleep(10);}`. there is no reason to treat the CPU like that :)

Comment: @RoiHatam This isn't supposed to be a practical example.

Comment: @duskwuff, you are right, in this particular example, it was caused by the output buffering. However in real code, which tends to be very similar to this example (main spawns a thread and jumps into a while cycle) I was using newlines in outputs. Adding a short usleep to while loop actually helped, even though I dont know why.

Comment: @Lorin: Would be interesting to know on which platform you are experiencing this.

Comment: @Lorin,  the reason the `usleep()` helps is running a thread requires a 'context' switch.  The context switch with the original `while()` loop only happens during execution slice timeouts of the overall process, even then, it (most often) will, when it is next 'dispatched' to run, continue to run the 'while()` loop.  Note: with a multiprocessor CPU the thread 'may' be run by a different CPU processor. and so not depend on a context switch.  With the `usleep()`, the `main()` execution gives up the CPU, thereby allowing the thread to execute